# UPI payment via QR node js

Tags: node.js

Is there any way to receive callback from UPI QR after user pay i am not using any third party gateway and generated QR via

upi://pay?pa=${upiId}&mc=&tid=${tid}&tr=${tr}&tn=${tn}&am=${amount}&cu=INR&url=${encodeURIComponent(callbackURL)}